# awk : set column value to '0' only if value NULL

Tags: awk

In space separated file fic.txt, if the last value is '', then set it '0'.

Example :

```
'A' 'B' 'C' '' 'E' '' |
'X' 'O' 'Y' 'T' 'W' '1' |
```

to

```
'A' 'B' 'C' '' 'E' '0' |
'X' 'O' 'Y' 'T' 'W' '1' |
```

I tried :

`awk '$6="\x27"0"\x27"'  fic.txt`     --> To set ALL values of the 6th column to '0'. It works.

But still issue to set to '0'  ONLY IF 6th column is ''.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _if the last value is ''_ - what is that `|` in the real last field?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$6=="\047\047" { $6="\047"0"\047"} 1'  fic.txt
```

I suggest to read awk guides such as [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) or [this](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_toc.html) in order to learn awk.

**updated**: Thanks @Kent and @EdMorton for your remarks.

Comment: you can declare a var: `-v q="'"` then use `q` in codes.

Comment: Always use octal escape sequences, never hex. See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/'' |/'0' |/" fil
'A' 'B' 'C' '' 'E' '0' |
'X' 'O' 'Y' 'T' 'W' '1' |
```

Based on the structure of your file, all lines are ending with the pipe "`|`" . Simple `sed` search and replace would do the task. For directly changing the input file, use `-i` or `-i.bak` flag with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` in awk to replace `''` (`'` is `\47` in octal) in "the last column" (`$6`) with `'0'`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\47\47/, "\47" "0" "\47", $6)} 1' bar
'A' 'B' 'C' '' 'E' '0' |
'X' 'O' 'Y' 'T' 'W' '1' |
```